# Is it bad for SEO to create a website without a domain (just on an IP address)?

Tags: seo, domains, ip-address, drupal

I'd like to create a Drupal 8.x.x website without a domain.

- The website is on a quite non-competitive field (only 4-5 competitors if at all)
- The website generally follows any standard of (Google's) SEO guidelines; it's just doesn't have a domain.

Should there be any major SEO problem (Google/Bing) creating a domainless website?

Comment: If it's going to be on the Internet, how will users find it without a domain name?  Will they be directed through a portal that points to an IP address?  Technically it's possible, but if you ever change hosting providers, your IP address will undoubtedly change and Google would probably consider it a brand new site all over again.

Comment: My intention is that users will find it only through search engines but indeed, if the hosting changes it might be needed to index it all over again; it's unlikely I'll leave my 5$ Linode machine but theoretically say I moved to a new host, what then? How to automatically let Google now elegantly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you would do.  I've never considered using just an IP address in Google Search Console or analytics.  I used to think I would never change vendors, but things change and the more you have invested in time and effort, the more you risk.  Can I ask why you're hesitant to create a domain?

Comment: Because I desire a more minimalist approach; less bureaucracy if I can...

Comment: The other issue that may impact your SEO will be lack of whois information.  With a domain name you would appear to be more legitimate versus someone who is just playing with test website on the Internet.  I'm guessing that would push you down in the SERPs.

Comment: One way to deal with the first problem is writing a bald note in the end of my only markdown document named `webdev.md`; it's the one and only document I use to document some facts and opinions about web development and available on my GitHub profile; while it does cover the first problem, the second one you mention (lack of WHOIS data) remain.

Comment: "My intention is that users will find it only through search engines" but why? That means you are willing to put all your business up to the will of any search engine (and people typically think only about one). It means if you get delisted for example, or badly listed, you accept not getting any business any more? What do you achieve exactly by not doing a domain?  That is certainly not to pay less, as domains are really not costly, but in fact build your presence online and make you independent. If you do not have one, you are also at the mercy of the owner of the IP address, your webhost.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The main audience of that site comes from Google and the competition is low (no more than 5 serious competitors). Domainless website saves me bureaucracy (which I hate), using a charging card (debit) which I prefer not to if I can, and also, some money if I buy many domains frequently. `If you do not have one, you are also at the mercy of the owner of the IP address, your webhost.` please care to explain a bit more in comments or in an answer.

Comment: If you have a domain you can decide today to map it to `192.0.2.1` because this is where your current host is. If tomorrow you decide to change, or your webhost decided to cut your service for whatever right or wrong reasons, or it becomes bankrupt, or it has an earthquake, etc.. etc... you just remap your domain to another IP address of another host, you are hence indenpendant. Basing all your business on the will of external companies, like search engines and hosting companies seems very risky for very little gain. No bureaucracy to buy a domain. How do you pay Google ads and hosting?

Comment: Also HTTPS and URLs with IP addresses do not mix well. You will have a lot of problems getting a recognized certificate for that...

Comment: I don't use Google ads (only organic - again, this is a field with almost no competition at all in comparison to other fields + the site is local); as for now I am on a contract for more than 1 year either for a domain or a hosting; then I should make a prepaid debit card and buy domains with it. What you say regarding to SSL is perhaps the best reason for me to consider buying a domain for that particular site after all.

Comment: Side note: All my domains are local.

Comment: Oh and also, @PatrickMevzek I think everything is a gamble in some sense with or without a domain (with a domain is surely better): Organic/adwords/Google my Business and so forth. Some types of businesses will always get most customers from the main search engine in their era, I believe. It's Google since 1998, I personally don't see it changed soon; not all businesses are fit to be published in FaceBook/Instagram and such, I think.

Comment: "I personally don't see it changed soon". Obviously it is a chicken and egg problem, if noone wants to exit from the mentality that there is only one search engine, and that noone can live without it, then obviously this specific search engine will retain its dominant spot for a long time. As for "not all businesses are fit to be published in FaceBook/Instagram" I was not even thinking of that, do you know that there were businesses online - and working - even before Facebook, Instagram, or the others existed? Again to summarize, your domain name is your online identity. You control it, or not

Comment: I can think outside that mentality of one search engine but I didn't see good evidence that most people will use other one... `o you know that there were businesses online - and working - even before Facebook, Instagram, or the others existed?` I didn't think otherwise... Sorry if I interpreted you wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it bad for SEO to create a website without a domain (just on an IP address)?

Search Engines always suggests you to create websites that are easy to use and serve the content/services that the users are looking for. So, yes, this indirectly affects your SEO because of the following reasons:

- **Not having a domain name that users can remember** (Your IP address lacks credibility and majority of the people cannot remember the IP address for sure.)
- **Every time, you change your host, a new IP address will be assigned to your website.** (This means, your website will be treated as completely new unless you use "Change of Address" tool on Google Search Console and similar for other SE if they provide such options.)
- **Lack of Credibility.** (Not having a whois registrar or record will make your users think whether your site is legitimate or not. This will affect your business and bounce rates or no conversions will drop your rankings sooner)

Apart from the above for SEO, this decision also poses a huge potential risk to your business. Here's why:

- Hosting only using IP makes you rely on your provider. If the provider shuts down the company or stops their services for whatsoever reasons, you'll be at loss.

> Regarding your stand on using a charging card or saving money on buying a domain name:

- Buying a domain name is the most beneficial approach as this can be owned by you as long as you renew the domain accordingly. So saving money on buying a domain name is only beneficial when you setup a website which you will discard in the near future.
- About providing your details to charge your card. If you're hesitant to put your details, how will your users pay for the business? Also, you do not lose anything on putting up your information.
- If you're worried about your personal information being shown on WHOIS, you can register the domain privately. (You do not have to pay extra money to hide your personal information on WHOIS if you register your domain with a EU registrar)

Comment: Thank you; also, the issue of TLS is very important that you mentioned (maybe the most important and the most hard to handle with). Also, BTW, Israeli domains can't be bought privately... This is good for world wide domains.

Comment: Just use a company address or pay for the privacy. I'm not sure on Israeli domains though